# How close the value of correlation coefficient (r) has to be to 1 to call it a strong positive relationship?

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to find the linear relationship between a few variables. If you look at the graph below, it feels like there is a moderate positive correlation.

[image]

And If I look at the numerical values(given below), it looks like it has a positive strong relationship as some values hover around 70-80. 
[image]

So, how close the value of r has to be in order to say that it really has a strong positive relationship. Is there any well-defined range?

Comment: No; there isn't. It depends on context and what can reasonably be expected.  It's admittedly hard for beginners to get to grips with so vague an idea. I am being only a little facetious in saying that a strong correlation is whatever reviewers in your field regard as such. Not every word has to be defined or definable even in technical discussion: consider "interesting" and "useful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One source for you:

According to **Ratner (2009)**: "Values between 0.7 and 1.0 (−0.7 and −1.0) indicate a strong positive (negative) linear relationship".

**References**

Ratner, B. (2009). The correlation coefficient: Its values range between+ 1/− 1, or do they? *Journal of Targeting, Measurement and Analysis for Marketing, 17(2),* 139-142.